# How to convert an string with array form to an array?

Tags: python, arrays, django, string

I got a string in this form

```
payload = ["Text 1", "Text 2"]
```

I want to use `Text 2` as an object. How can I return it?

**UPDATE**
I'm making a function which returns a [generic template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/receipt-template) Facebook API.
The first `payload` works well, but I want to return a `string` and a `object` in the second `payload` ( result )

```
button = [
            {
                "type": "postback",
                "title": "Buy item",
                "payload": "Buy this item: " + (product['id'])
            },
            {
                "type": "postback",
                "title": "Add to wishlist",
                "payload": result
            }
        ]
```

My second payload should look like this:

```
payload = {
            'Order_item',
            product['title']
        }
```

Because I got this error `[buttons][1][payload] must be a UTF-8 encoded string` so I did convert it and it returns a **STRING** in this form `["Order_item", "Ledverlichting Fiets Blauw"]`

Because I want that when a Facebook user clicks on a postback ( Add to wishlist ), the `product['title']` value will be save in Django database. And `product['title']` is the `Text 2` in the question above.

Comment: errr `payload[1]` ? you want an array of 1 string? can you be more specific?

Comment: return payload[1] ?

Comment: I will update my question to be more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the string then trim and keep splitting/trimming to get all parts that you want to have in list

```
s = 'payload = ["Text 1", "Text 2"]'
items = s.strip()[1:-1]
#if 'payload = ' is also part of string you need to split it also by '=' so it would be:
#items = s.split("=").strip()[1:-1] 
l = [item.strip()[1:-1] for item in items.split(",")]
```

then you have list of string that you can iterate, get n-th item and so on

```
the_item = l[1]
return the_item
```

Comment: You are just returning all the string

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you want a string object, you can get the specific index in the array(first spot = 0, second spot = 1, etc).

you can save the string object contained in the array like this:

```
payload = ["Text 1", "Text 2"]
s = payload[1]
```

and than you can return the s object.

Comment: I have tried this before but it's not an array it returns `"`

Comment: if it returns an empty string it means that the index 1 in the array is an empty string, make sure that the value you need to be in the array actually is in the array.

Comment: That's not array - the whole `["Text 1", "Text 2"]` is a string ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
>>> payload = ["t1", "t2"]
>>> t2 = [1,2]
>>> eval(payload[1])
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a string that was in strictly list format and simply passing it through eval() worked.